# Is there a module/hook for permissions for list values?

Tags: 7, users, forms

Say I have a text list field attached to a node with the following values:

- Apples
- Oranges
- Grapes
- Kiwi
- Strawberries
- Pears
- Bananas

But I want to give some options only to some roles, for example:

- Only **Administrators** can select Strawberries.
- Only **Anonymous** can select Kiwi.
- Only **Role C** can select Pears.

Is there a module for this?  Or, if I was going to code it myself, is there a hook to start from?

This is for Drupal 8 but if there was a solution only for 7, that would be interesting to look at too.

Comment: I can't be absolutely sure, but I think that the best way is restrict values per role using hook_form_alter

Comment: Would it be OK that all those roles can "see" (but not "select") all those values?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens In this case, yes, I don't mind if roles see the values but can't select them, as long as there is some way to differentiate the values they cannot select so that I don't annoy them by letting them select things they can't.

Answer (score 1):

## This is Drupal 7 solution

Using `hook_form_alter`, you can unset some of the options based on the user role. 
For example look at this list of `article` content type  (`field_list`)

[image]

It is the result of `kpr()` on its form

[image]

simply use this code

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    global $user;    
    if($form_id == "article_node_form"){
        //kpr($form);
        if(in_array('SOME_ROLE', $user->roles)) 
            unset($form['field_list']['und']['#options'][2]);
   }
}
```

This is the result

[image]